# Converting all Terms in a List to Title case

Tags: python

I have a list:

```
['CHEVRON' 'GUNVOR' 'P66' 'SHELL']
```

I need them to be converted to title case format.

I'm currently looping through them but there must be a simpler way.

Intended output:

```
['Chevron', 'Gunvor', 'P66', 'Shell']
```

Comment: There isn't a simper way than looping through them!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [35]: L = ['CHEVRON', 'GUNVOR', 'P66', 'SHELL']                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

In [36]: list(map(str.title, L))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
Out[36]: ['Chevron', 'Gunvor', 'P66', 'Shell']

In [37]: [s.title() for s in L]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
Out[37]: ['Chevron', 'Gunvor', 'P66', 'Shell']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l = ['CHEVRON','GUNVOR','P66','SHELL']

l =[x.title() for x in l]
```

here you go

Comment: if you are accessing all elements of a list then you have to loop the whole list, now the implementation may vary, like using map, but that is also internally looping.

Comment: The complexity can't be less than O(n)